# Can I develop Qt GUI in Xcode with Python ??

Tags: python, xcode, qt, pyqt4

I am a newbie Python programer. I have developed my logic in Python, i want to develop the GUI with Qt using PyQt4. How do I start about ?? Can I start in XCode ??

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you selected perfect combination to GUI programming. Python + PyQt helps for FAST and effective on GUI design

1. <s>Eclipse + PyDev(extension) to perfect python environment. DEBUGging, Auto Complete, Pep8, PyLint, PyDev Console, Code Analysis, PyUnit ... 
   http://pydev.org/</s>  EDIT: see below
2. Qt-Designer and Qt-Assistant, quite awesome ! http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/ http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html http://wiki.python.org/moin/JonathanGardnerPyQtTutorial
3. Pyuic4, Pyrrc4 and other console tools key advantages. You can design aui with qtdesigner and you can use that for any qt platform or language.
4. Bonus, py-installer; cross-platform python distribution tool. It supports nearly all libraries builtin include pyqt,lxml...

PS: I am exactly using this environment and we finished a server-client in 2 months from zero

EDIT: With [pycharm-community edition](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) release, we migrated to it. It is absolutely fantastic for any type python development environment.